How to navigate to a [slug] loaded from a database in sveltekit
I am still pretty new to Sveltekit and Supabase but I want to make a website that grabs data from a table in Supabase and using a slug to navigate to a different url depending on what the user inputs in a simple form. Currently it works just fine when I run it locally but as soon as I push it to Github pages it throws a 404 error.
This is how I am currently navigating to the page.
  // Search supabase for keyword
  async function searchDatabase() {
    // Checks to see if form is empty upon submission
    if (topic.trim() === '') {
      help = 'The form is empty. Please enter a fruit. (hint: enter "Apple")';
      return;
    }

    // Finds the desired keyword in supabase table
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('Topics')
      .select('Description')
      .eq('Topic', topic);

    console.log('Search result:', { data, error });

    if (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      help = `Error fetching data: ${error.message}`;
    } else if (data.length === 0) {
      help = 'We could not find this fruit. Try again.';
    } else {
      goto(`${base}/${topic}`);
    }
  }

And this is how I am handling loading the page.
import type { TopicData } from '$lib/types';
import { supabase } from '$lib/supabaseClient';
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ params }) => {
  const { slug } = params;
  console.log('Fetching data for slug:', slug);

  try {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('Topics')
      .select('Topic, Description')
      .eq('Topic', slug)
      .single();

    if (error || !data) {
      console.error('Error fetching data from Supabase:', error ? error.message : 'No data found');
      return {
        error: 'Not found'
      };
    }

    console.log('Data fetched successfully:', data);

    return {
      topic: data.Topic,
      description: data.Description
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Unexpected error:', err);
    return {
      status: 500,
      error: 'Internal Server Error'
    };
  }
};



Are you using adapter-static? If yes, after you have built the app, does previewing it on your computer works?

Yeah, I am using adapter-static. When I preview it it works fine it is only when I push it to GitHub pages that it does not want to load the data from Supabase.

I'm guessing the problem is goto(`${base}/${topic}`). adapter-static only works for static websites, i.e. websites where all routes are known at build time. If I remember right, adapter-static will first render the start page, and from there find all the <a> elements on that page, and then render those pages, etc. So if a page can't be reaches through an <a> element this way, adapter-static can't prerender it.

I switched to the node adapter but it still returns a 404 page. If it helps here is a link to my Github repository https://github.com/CameronRJohnson/Website-Generator

If you use adapter-node, then you can't host your website on GitHub Pages, because you can only host statically build websites there. Statically build websites do have their limitations, and support for searching is one of them, because searching usually is something dynamic (not known at build time) and often need to happen on the server after deployment. But if you don't have much data in your database (and that data can't change/be added/be removed), then you can retrieve all of the data in your load() function, and add filtering capabilities on the client page instead.
